# c++ winsock strange error

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I am making a C++ network application and I am creating the server,but I have a strange problem.When I call listen,it should wait for a connection,but the application continues like if the listen call doesn't exist.This is my code:

```
#include "includes.hpp"
using namespace std;
SOCKET sv;
WSADATA w;

int serverStart(int port)
{
    int error = WSAStartup(0x0202,&w);
    if(error)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error de startup:%i",error);
        return false;
    }
    if(w.wVersion != 0x0202)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error versión incorrecta de wsadata: Esperada 202.Obtenida %X",w.wVersion);
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    sv = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(sv == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error de socket");
        return false;
    }
    if(bind(sv,(LPSOCKADDR)&addr,sizeof(addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error de bind");
        return false;
    }
    fprintf(stdout,"Listen..");
    listen(sv,SOMAXCONN);
    fprintf(stdout,"Fin");
}
```

I am calling serverStart from main.I also have the firewall deactivated to see if it was the problem,but it didn't worked.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the call to `listen` failed. The function returns an `int` that you can use to see if the call succeeded or if it failed. Grab that return code and see what it is. You can see the error codes and what they mean on [the documentation page for listen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms739168(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `listen` only places the socket in a state that accepts incomming connections. In order to actually accept a connection, you need to call the `accept` function. The call to `accept` blocks the program until you get a connection.

```
SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
// Accept a client socket
ClientSocket = accept(sv, NULL, NULL);
if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(sv);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I am not saying that it doesn't accept,i am sayng that it doesn't listen for connections.

Comment: If you include the call to `accept`, then it will listen for connections. If you get a connection, it will also accept it. I tested your code with the call to `accept` and I can see that it really does listen for connections http://imgur.com/lXzABt1

Answer (score 0):

listen() is not a blocking function. It just puts the socket into listening state. It is accept() that is the blocking function, and recv(), and send().